# Trying to work out a sum of the product of binomials that is not quite Vandermonde's identity,

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I know Vandermonde's identity gives:

$$
\binom{m+n}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^{r}{\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k}}
$$

I have something that is almost but not quite that, namely I have:

$$
\frac{\sum_{k=s}^{r}{\binom{k}{s}{\binom{m}{k}}{\binom{n}{r-k}}}}{\binom{m+n}{r}}
$$

For the special case where $s=0$, noting that $\binom{x}{0}=1,\space\forall{x}$, the sum collapses to Vandermonde's identity which cancels with the bottom giving $1$.

I've done some brute force evaluation up to 5 terms but I am not convinced of the pre-factor. I know I end up with something like:

$$
a_s\frac{\left(m\right)_i\left(n\right)_{r-s}}{\left(m+n\right)_s}
$$

But to be brutally honest I am some of those expansions are pages long and the chances of making a mistake or missing a term is ridiculously high. I think $a_s$'s are binomial coefficients but I am so non-confident of my rough work, I think it might be $\binom{r+1}{s}$ or $\binom{r}{s}$ or maybe $r\binom{r+1}{s}$. I am reasonably confident that there are running factorials and that the number of terms on the top matches the number of terms on the bottom.

Are there any identities I can use to:

- Figure out what the $a_s$ constants are
- Get to the running fractions from the sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In seeking to evaluate

$${m+n\choose r}^{-1}
\sum_{k=s}^r {k\choose s} {m\choose k} {n\choose r-k}$$

we first note that

$${k\choose s} {m\choose k}
= \frac{m!}{s! \times (k-s)! \times (m-k)!}
= {m\choose s} {m-s\choose m-k}$$

so we get

$${m+n\choose r}^{-1} {m\choose s}
\sum_{k=s}^r {m-s\choose m-k} {n\choose r-k}.$$

The inner sum is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{r-s} {m-s\choose m-r+k} {n\choose k}
= \sum_{k=0}^{r-s} {m-s\choose r-s-k} {n\choose k}
\\ = [z^{r-s}] (1+z)^{m-s}
\sum_{k=0}^{r-s} z^k {n\choose k}.$$

Here the coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit of the sum and
we get

$$[z^{r-s}] (1+z)^{m-s}
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^k {n\choose k}
= [z^{r-s}] (1+z)^{m+n-s} = {m+n-s\choose r-s}.$$

We thus obtain the closed form

$${m+n\choose r}^{-1} {m\choose s}
{m+n-s\choose r-s}.$$

Here we presumably have $m+n\ge r$ or $m+n\lt 0$ to get a value we may
invert.

Comment: Over answered! Thank you very much. Let me know if you want credit for this if I get the paper I’m working on published.

Comment: Mapping it back into my equation gives the exact answer my best run through had got (but I had four other attempts which didn’t work the same) also in my case $m+n\gt r$ and $0 \leq s \leq r$

Comment: I think we don’t need the coefficient extractor, given Vandermonde’s identity once the inner sum has been rearranged the closed form follows directly (though thanks for the coefficient extractor example, and it wouldn’t have been obvious without the rearrangement)

Comment: Vandermonde will do as you say.